# RSpec does not find my view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I get this error when I run my test

```
spec/helpers/bikes_helper_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>':
uninitialized constant BikesHelper (NameError)
```

**bikes_helper**

```
require "spec_helper"

describe BikesHelper do

  describe "#km_until_next_service" do
    it 'returns a human readable number' do
      expect(km_until_next_service(1000)).to eq '1000 kilometers'
    end

  end
end
```

**app/helpers/bikes_helper.rb**

```
module BikesHelper

  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper


  def km_until_next_service(km_untill_next)

    if km_untill_next == 0
      return "NOW"
    elsif (km_untill_next < 0)
      return "Overdue by #{number_to_human(km_untill_next, unit: :distance)}"
    elsif (km_untill_next > 0)
      return "In #{number_to_human(km_untill_next, unit: :distance)}"
    end

  end
end
```

Any idea why it does not recognise BikesHelper?

Comment: Does `spec_helper` load the entire Rails environment, more recently this is done in `rails_helper`, trying requiring that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

instead of

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

Comment: Hehe, that was it! Thanks! :-D

Comment: Great answer! =)